# apache FTPClient password failing when there are special caracters in it

Tags: apache, ftp

I am using the apache FTPClient and it is not accepting a password with a special character.  The password has an @ symbol in it.  I am using the following code:

```
FTPClient fc = new FTPClient();
fc.connect(url);
fc.login(username, password);
```

This is giving me UnknownHostException.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think maybe the UnknownHostException means something?

Comment: Well i think it is trying to use what is after the 1st @ symbol.  as part of the host name url.  I tried using the encoded %40 instead of the first @ symbol but that didnt work :(

Comment: what are the values of `url` and `username`? let's just pretend `password = abc@123`

Comment: well as an example the url would look like thisIsmyurl.com and the username as simple as "user1" and yes that password is exactly like what i am using

Comment: What exactly is the URL you're using?

Comment: it is an internal url. But I just figured it out.  I was passing arguments into the jar file.  One being the fulling formed url: user1:p@ssword@myurl.com.  Then in the code that is parsed to get the username password and url.  I made sure that the username and the password wer coming across correctly but when doing a split to get the url, i forgot to check for multiple @ symbols... boo on me... anyway thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Sometimes all it takes to figure out what's wrong with your code is to try to explain it to someone else, at which point you see something and go "wow, that doesn't make any sense at all, does it" :D